# Truncate long links in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a page using Bootstrap 3.1 wherein if the length of an HTML link is way too long, it overflows out and creates a horizontal scroll in the mobile version. Is there a way to truncate it and replace it by ellipses?

Example:

[image]

What I need is that instead of extending out, it should get truncated before the border. ANy idea how to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure that the container has `overflow: hidden` to keep the text from flowing outside of the border and give it `text-overflow: ellipsis` to give the link the ellipsis.

```css
.box {
  background: #f99;
  border: 1px solid #c66;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="nowrap">A really long piece of text</span>
</div>

<div class="box ellipsis">
  <span class="nowrap">A really long piece of text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, this is the page I'm talking about: http://planet.kde.org.uk/ I could simply hide the overflowing text (hyperlink), but that won't be a good thing to do.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to add the `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` to the parent of the `a` tag unfortunately. In this case that's the `p` tag.

Comment: Alright, I'll try and figure out a way. The issue is that in the p itself, there might be some text that might get overflowed, for example links not in an anchor tag. I think I'll have to go the JS way :/